# how can i handle a checkbox value being sent from the form to the php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Trying to understand how to handle the values sent from a checkbox. Got the form on one page which accepts a name value email etc then also a "mailingList" checkbox value but im struggling to handle the set and unset values. The following code is the $_POST method from the form page.

```
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    $retyped = trim($_POST['conf_pwd']);
     $firstname = trim($_POST['fname']);
     $lastname = trim($_POST['lname']);
     $company = trim($_POST['company']);
     $mailingList = $_POST['mailingListCheckbox'];
    require_once('./includes/register_user_pdo.inc.php');
    }
```

I currently have this if statement to try and set the value of "mailingListValue" to try and handle it correctly but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    if (!isset($mailingList)) {
    $mailingListValue = 0;
    }
    else {
    $mailingListValue = 1;
    }
```

Any tips on the if statement or what im doing wrong would be much appreciated!Thanks for any help!

edit: form

```
<input name="mailingListCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="mailingListCheckbox" value="1" checked="checked">
<label for="mailingListCheckbox">Yes, I would like to receive alerts and updates from the MSF</label>
```

Comment: Can you show the form in HTML as well?

Comment: sure ill edit my post

Comment: please var_dump $mailingList and write us the output

Comment: Check to see if your form elements are named and no typos. I.e.: `name="register"`

Comment: change `$mailingList = $_POST['mailingListCheckbox'];` to `$mailingList = isset($_POST['mailingListCheckbox']) ? 1 : 0;`? Then you would not need the `if/else`

Comment: If you are 'setting' `$mailingList` then it is going to be 'set'. It is more than likely 'null' and you need to use `isnull`

Comment: Need to see the complete form. If you don't have an element named `register` which most likely is a submit button, then nothing will pass.

Comment: yea i have that fred, thanks, if i post the whole form it marks it up in the box annoyingly!

Comment: Ok, just checking @FindlayMack

Comment: what is the `name` value of your checkbox?

Comment: This method may be better to use `if (!isset($_POST['mailingListCheckbox'])){$mailingListValue = 0;...` @FindlayMack

Answer (score 3):

Edit your PHP code

```
if ($mailingList == 1) {
$mailingListValue = 1;
}
else {
$mailingListValue = 0;
}
```

If your checkbox is checked, the `$mailingList` value will be "1"

Comment: aww shi- you beat me haha +1 for getting ther first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use @Sean 's method above (in the question comments) and do the test in when set `$mailingList` or test if a real condition is set to `$mailingList` i.e...

```
if($mailingList == 1) {
    //do something
} else {
    // dont do something
}
```

Comment: If you attempt to assign `$var1` to an undefined var then `$var1` will NOT be set.

Comment: Literally just tried it. Good work sir! removing from my answer.

Comment: But if that is the case then how is it not going to be set in OP's code if the checkbox is unticked? Or does op have the name of the checkbox wrong and it is always unset?

Comment: Dunno.  The OP's code as posted should work, but throw E_NOTICE, undefined index mailingListCheckbox, when not checked.

Comment: Also, damn I love PHP and it's "basicness"

Comment: @MichaelCoxon thanks for your reply, its still not working however and im just getting a error 23000 being returned from sql... which makes me think there is something going on with my database.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes i am getting that undefined index when it was unchecked but the if statement should solve that shouldn't it?

Comment: @FindlayMack: No, you're getting it because in this `$mailingList = $_POST['mailingListCheckbox'];` the `$_POST` index `mailingListCheckbox` does not exist when it is not checked.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ahh ok. Sorry relatively new to this! So if im trying to either enter a boolean value into a table is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just do everything in one:

```
$mailingListValue = isset($_POST['mailingListCheckbox']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Ternary's are a pain to read. I would suggest against using them if you want your code to be readable.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon To each his own.

Comment: Very true. Just been doing some .NET at work lately. Last guy love ternary's. had some like 150 characters long with parentheses all over the place. NIGHTMARE MODE